# Post JSON Jquery show

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm still trying to get a JSON response, deplegue in a div ... I pass to mostar and tell them

> script

```
$('select#mes').on('change',function(){

    var valor = $(this).val();
    var route = "http://localhost/UJOBB/public/ADIC/ListaM";
    var token = document.getElementById('token').getAttribute('content')


    if(valor != null){

        $.ajax({
        url: route,
        headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token},
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data:{mes: valor},
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $("#resultado").html("Procesando, espere por favor...");
                },
                success: function(users){
                    $("#resultado").html(JSON.stringify(users));       
                },
                error: function() {

                }
            });
    }
    else{
    }


});
```

the post worked ok and I json response but fails to deploy in row

> JSON response

```
{"users":[{"id":1,"Fecha":"Vier 06 Mayo","EquipoA":"Edu","EquipoB":"Juan XXIII","Categoria":"sub18","Cancha":"EDU","Hora":"2016-06-14 16:00:00","Numero_J1":"94","Nombre_J1":"Sebastián","Apellido_J1":"Vilizio","Check_J1":1,"Numero_J2":"127","Nombre_J2":"Santiago","Apellido_J2":"Gomez","Check_J2":1,"Mes":"May","created_at":"2016-06-14 18:57:37","updated_at":"2016-06-14 18:57:37"},{"id":2,"Fecha":"Sáb 07 Mayo","EquipoA":"Safa","EquipoB":"ISASA","Categoria":"sub18","Cancha":"Safa","Hora":"2016-06-14 16:15:00","Numero_J1":"45","Nombre_J1":"M.","Apellido_J1":"Fantauzzi","Check_J1":1,"Numero_J2":"141","Nombre_J2":"Diego","Apellido_J2":"Gomez","Check_J2":1,"Mes":"May","created_at":"2016-06-14 18:57:37","updated_at":"2016-06-14 18:57:37"},{"id":3,"Fecha":"Sáb 07 Mayo","EquipoA":"Safa","EquipoB":"ISASA","Categoria":"sub16","Cancha":"Safa","Hora":"2016-06-14 17:45:00","Numero_J1":"45","Nombre_J1":"Marcelo","Apellido_J1":"Fantauzzi","Check_J1":1,"Numero_J2":"141","Nombre_J2":"Diego","Apellido_J2":"Gomez","Check_J2":1,"Mes":"May","created_at":"2016-06-14 18:57:38","updated_at":"2016-06-14 18:57:38"},{"id":4,"Fecha":"Sáb 07 Mayo","EquipoA":"Safa","EquipoB":"ISASA","Categoria":"sub14","Cancha":"Safa","Hora":"2016-06-14 19:15:00","Numero_J1":"45","Nombre_J1":"Marcelo","Apellido_J1":"Fantauzzi","Check_J1":1,"Numero_J2":"141","Nombre_J2":"Diego","Apellido_J2":"Gomez","Check_J2":1,"Mes":"May","created_at":"2016-06-14 18:57:38","updated_at":"2016-06-14 18:57:38"},{"id":5,"Fecha":"Sáb 07 Mayo","EquipoA":"Seminario","EquipoB":"Elbio","Categoria":"sub18","Cancha":"Seminario","Hora":"2016-06-14 15:30:00","Numero_J1":"52","Nombre_J1":"M.","Apellido_J1":"Rial","Check_J1":1,"Numero_J2":"120","Nombre_J2":"Jose","Apellido_J2":"Perez","Check_J2":1,"Mes":"May","created_at":"2016-06-14 18:57:38","updated_at":"2016-06-14 18:57:38"},{"id":6,"Fecha":"Sáb 07 Mayo","EquipoA":"Seminario","EquipoB":"Elbio","Categoria":"sub14","Cancha":"Seminario","Hora":"2016-06-14 17:00:00","Numero_J1":"52","Nombre_J1":"M.","Apellido_J1":"Rial","Check_J1":1,"Numero_J2":"120","Nombre_J2":"Jose","Apellido_J2":"Perez","Check_J2":1,"Mes":"May","created_at":"2016-06-14 18:57:38","updated_at":"2016-06-14 18:57:38"},{"id":7,"Fecha":"Sáb 07 Mayo","EquipoA":"Seminario","EquipoB":"Elbio","Categoria":"sub16","Cancha":"Seminario","Hora":"2016-06-14 18:30:00","Numero_J1":null,"Nombre_J1":null,"Apellido_J1":null,"Check_J1":1,"Numero_J2":"120","Nombre_J2":"Jose","Apellido_J2":"Perez","Check_J2":1,"Mes":"May","created_at":"2016-06-14 18:57:38","updated_at":"2016-06-14 18:57:38"},{"id":8,"Fecha":"Sáb 07 Mayo","EquipoA":"La Mennais","EquipoB":"Frances","Categoria":"sub14","Cancha":"La Mennais","Hora":"2016-06-14 16:30:00","Numero_J1":"48","Nombre_J1":"A.","Apellido_J1":"Labiuza","Check_J1":1,"Numero_J2":"134","Nombre_J2":"G.","Apellido_J2":"Brum","Check_J2":1,"Mes":"May","created_at":"2016-06-14 18:57:38","updated_at":"2016-06-14 18:57:38"},{"id":9,"Fecha":"Sáb 07 Mayo","EquipoA":"La Mennais","EquipoB":"Frances","Categoria":"sub16","Cancha":"La Mennais","Hora":"2016-06-14 18:00:00","Numero_J1":"48","Nombre_J1":"A.","Apellido_J1":"Labiuza","Check_J1":1,"Numero_J2":"134","Nombre_J2":"G.","Apellido_J2":"Brum","Check_J2":1,"Mes":"May","created_at":"2016-06-14 18:57:38","updated_at":"2016-06-14 18:57:38"},{"id":10,"Fecha":"Sáb 07 Mayo","EquipoA":"UAS","EquipoB":"Preu","Categoria":"sub18","Cancha":"UAS","Hora":"2016-06-14 15:00:00","Numero_J1":"39","Nombre_J1":"Alvaro","Apellido_J1":"Aunchayna","Check_J1":1,"Numero_J2":"139","Nombre_J2":"G.","Apellido_J2":"Cancela","Check_J2":1,"Mes":"May","created_at":"2016-06-14 18:57:38","updated_at":"2016-06-14 18:57:38"},{"id":11,"Fecha":"Sáb 07 Mayo","EquipoA":"Impulso","EquipoB":"San Jose Prov","Categoria":"sub16","Cancha":"UAS","Hora":"2016-06-14 16:30:00","Numero_J1":"39","Nombre_J1":"Alvaro","Apellido_J1":"Aunchayna","Check_J1":1,"Numero_J2":"139","Nombre_J2":"G.","Apellido_J2":"Cancela","Check_J2":1,"Mes":"May","created_at":"2016-06-14 18:57:38","updated_at":"2016-06-14 18:57:38"},{"id":12,"Fecha":"Vier 13 Mayo","EquipoA":"L. Militar","EquipoB":"Isasa","Categoria":"sub18","Cancha":"L. Militar","Hora":"2016-06-14 15:30:00","Numero_J1":"39","Nombre_J1":"Alvaro","Apellido_J1":"Aunchayna","Check_J1":1,"Numero_J2":"39","Nombre_J2":"Alvaro ","Apellido_J2":"Aunchayna ","Check_J2":1,"Mes":"May","created_at":"2016-06-14 18:57:38","updated_at":"2016-06-14 18:57:38"},{"id":13,"Fecha":"Sáb 14 Mayo","EquipoA":"San Juan ","EquipoB":"Frances","Categoria":"sub14","Cancha":"San Juan ","Hora":"2016-06-14 17:00:00","Numero_J1":"54","Nombre_J1":"D.","Apellido_J1":"Spilman","Check_J1":1,"Numero_J2":"23","Nombre_J2":"G","Apellido_J2":"Cardozo","Check_J2":1,"Mes":"May","created_at":"2016-06-14 18:57:38","updated_at":"2016-06-14 18:57:38"},{"id":14,"Fecha":"Sáb 14 Mayo","EquipoA":"San Juan ","EquipoB":"Frances","Categoria":"sub16","Cancha":"San Juan ","Hora":"2016-06-14 18:30:00","Numero_J1":"54","Nombre_J1":"D.","Apellido_J1":"Spilman","Check_J1":1,"Numero_J2":"23","Nombre_J2":"G","Apellido_J2":"Cardozo","Check_J2":1,"Mes":"May","created_at":"2016-06-14 18:57:38","updated_at":"2016-06-14 18:57:38"},{"id":15,"Fecha":"Sáb 21 Mayo","EquipoA":"UAS","EquipoB":"Elbio","Categoria":"sub18","Cancha":"UAS","Hora":"2016-06-14 12:30:00","Numero_J1":"141","Nombre_J1":"Diego","Apellido_J1":"Gomez","Check_J1":1,"Numero_J2":"131","Nombre_J2":"D.","Apellido_J2":"Lopez","Check_J2":1,"Mes":"May","created_at":"2016-06-14 18:57:38","updated_at":"2016-06-14 18:57:38"},{"id":16,"Fecha":"Sáb 21 Mayo","EquipoA":"Crandon","EquipoB":"Sta. Elena","Categoria":"sub14","Cancha":"Crandon","Hora":"2016-06-14 16:45:00","Numero_J1":"64","Nombre_J1":"W.","Apellido_J1":"Chamorro","Check_J1":1,"Numero_J2":"133","Nombre_J2":"P.","Apellido_J2":"Borges","Check_J2":1,"Mes":"May","created_at":"2016-06-14 18:57:38","updated_at":"2016-06-14 18:57:38"},{"id":17,"Fecha":"Sáb 21 Mayo","EquipoA":"Crandon","EquipoB":"Sta. Elena","Categoria":"sub16","Cancha":"Crandon","Hora":"2016-06-14 18:15:00","Numero_J1":"64","Nombre_J1":"W.","Apellido_J1":"Chamorro","Check_J1":1,"Numero_J2":"133","Nombre_J2":"P.","Apellido_J2":"Borges","Check_J2":1,"Mes":"May","created_at":"2016-06-14 18:57:38","updated_at":"2016-06-14 18:57:38"},{"id":18,"Fecha":"Sáb 21 Mayo","EquipoA":"Seminario","EquipoB":"San Juan II","Categoria":"sub14","Cancha":"San Juan ","Hora":"2016-06-14 15:30:00","Numero_J1":"86","Nombre_J1":"M.","Apellido_J1":"Correa","Check_J1":1,"Numero_J2":"126","Nombre_J2":"D.","Apellido_J2":"Orrico","Check_J2":1,"Mes":"May","created_at":"2016-06-14 18:57:38","updated_at":"2016-06-14 18:57:38"},{"id":19,"Fecha":"Sáb 21 Mayo","EquipoA":"La Mennais","EquipoB":"San Juan ","Categoria":"sub16","Cancha":"San Juan ","Hora":"2016-06-14 17:00:00","Numero_J1":"86","Nombre_J1":"M.","Apellido_J1":"Correa","Check_J1":1,"Numero_J2":"126","Nombre_J2":"D.","Apellido_J2":"Orrico","Check_J2":1,"Mes":"May","created_at":"2016-06-14 18:57:38","updated_at":"2016-06-14 18:57:38"},{"id":20,"Fecha":"Sáb 21 Mayo","EquipoA":"La Mennais","EquipoB":"San Juan ","Categoria":"sub18","Cancha":"San Juan ","Hora":"2016-06-14 18:30:00","Numero_J1":"86","Nombre_J1":"M.","Apellido_J1":"Correa","Check_J1":1,"Numero_J2":"126","Nombre_J2":"D.","Apellido_J2":"Orrico","Check_J2":1,"Mes":"May","created_at":"2016-06-14 18:57:38","updated_at":"2016-06-14 18:57:38"},{"id":21,"Fecha":"Sáb 21 Mayo","EquipoA":"Safa","EquipoB":"Juan XXIII","Categoria":"sub18","Cancha":"Safa","Hora":"2016-06-14 16:15:00","Numero_J1":"119","Nombre_J1":"Sandra","Apellido_J1":"Lopez","Check_J1":1,"Numero_J2":"138","Nombre_J2":"N","Apellido_J2":"Daguerre","Check_J2":1,"Mes":"May","created_at":"2016-06-14 18:57:38","updated_at":"2016-06-14 18:57:38"},{"id":22,"Fecha":"Sáb 21 Mayo","EquipoA":"Seminario","EquipoB":"Isasa","Categoria":"sub18","Cancha":"Seminario","Hora":"2016-06-14 17:00:00","Numero_J1":"47","Nombre_J1":"M.","Apellido_J1":"Galli","Check_J1":1,"Numero_J2":"127","Nombre_J2":"Santiago","Apellido_J2":"Gomez","Check_J2":1,"Mes":"May","created_at":"2016-06-14 18:57:38","updated_at":"2016-06-14 18:57:38"},{"id":23,"Fecha":"Sáb 21 Mayo","EquipoA":"Seminario","EquipoB":"Isasa","Categoria":"sub16","Cancha":"Seminario","Hora":"2016-06-14 18:30:00","Numero_J1":"47","Nombre_J1":"M.","Apellido_J1":"Galli","Check_J1":1,"Numero_J2":"127","Nombre_J2":"Santiago","Apellido_J2":"Gomez","Check_J2":1,"Mes":"May","created_at":"2016-06-14 18:57:38","updated_at":"2016-06-14 18:57:38"},{"id":24,"Fecha":"Sáb 28 Mayo","EquipoA":"Safa","EquipoB":"Impulso ","Categoria":"sub16","Cancha":"Safa","Hora":"2016-06-14 16:15:00","Numero_J1":"110","Nombre_J1":"G.","Apellido_J1":"Gonzalez","Check_J1":1,"Numero_J2":"120","Nombre_J2":"J.","Apellido_J2":"Perez","Check_J2":1,"Mes":"May","created_at":"2016-06-14 18:57:38","updated_at":"2016-06-14 18:57:38"},{"id":25,"Fecha":"Sáb 28 Mayo","EquipoA":"Safa","EquipoB":"Preu","Categoria":"sub18","Cancha":"Safa","Hora":"2016-06-14 17:45:00","Numero_J1":"110","Nombre_J1":"G.","Apellido_J1":"Gonzalez","Check_J1":1,"Numero_J2":"120","Nombre_J2":"J.","Apellido_J2":"Perez","Check_J2":1,"Mes":"May","created_at":"2016-06-14 18:57:38","updated_at":"2016-06-14 18:57:38"},{"id":26,"Fecha":"Sáb 28 Mayo","EquipoA":"San Juan ","EquipoB":"L. Militar","Categoria":"sub18","Cancha":"San Juan ","Hora":"2016-06-14 14:30:00","Numero_J1":"122","Nombre_J1":"M.","Apellido_J1":"Coghlan","Check_J1":1,"Numero_J2":"133","Nombre_J2":"P.","Apellido_J2":"Borges","Check_J2":1,"Mes":"May","created_at":"2016-06-14 18:57:38","updated_at":"2016-06-14 18:57:38"}]}
```

> html

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
        <th>Fecha</th>
        <th>Cancha</th>
        <th>Partido</th>
        <th>Juez - 1</th>
        <th>Juez - 2</th>
        <th>Estado</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <span id="resultado">0</span>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What does "fails to deploy in row" mean?  What are you expecting to happen and what is happening?  What does `JSON.stringify()` return for `users`?  Why are you using `.html()` and not `.text()`?

Comment: Try moving the span out of the table and then test it. I believe the issue could be with your html.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You can't put `<div>` directly in `<tbody>`. The contents of `<tbody>` need to be `<tr>`, and they need to contain `<td>` or `<th>`. The DIV needs to be in one of those.

Comment: Why `document.getElementById('token').getAttribute('content')` instead of `$('#token').attr('content')`?

Comment: token, because it is a system laravel

Comment: I need to deploy the json response tables, and can not yoked to logreue is JSON.stringify Use L () to see the chain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In success handler you have JSON object which you can use to populate the table.

```
...
success: function(data){
   var tbody = $('.table.table-striped > tbody');
   $(data.users).each(function(index, user){
     $('<tr />')
       .append($('<td />').html(user.Fecha))
       .append($('<td />').html(user.Categoria))
       .appendTo(tbody);
   });//each
}//success
...
```